# Stretch to bone constraint SHORTCUT in 2.81

Tags: rigging

In Blender 2.7x you press Shift+I to link a bone constraint to something by selecting both bones.
In Blender 2.81 that shortcut changed. What´s the shortcut for Bone constraint "stretch to"?
Thanks.